# Is there an explanation for Batroc's accent?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

In the beginning of the Winter Soldier, we meet Batroc, supposedly an Algerian national (so says Pierce later), and if I remember correctly ex-DGSE (which should be incompatible with him being an Algerian, but is not shocking) and ex-French Foreign Legion.

However when he starts speaking, he has the thickest Quebec accent I have ever heard. Indeed he is played by Georges St-Pierre.

The accent is quite surprising to hear for a French native speaker, and I have heard some English native speakers say that they had noticed the accent and found it inconsistent with the character background. The accent is really really hard to ignore and sounds completely out-of-character (imagine a Texan cow-boy speaking with a cockney accent).

I don't really understand why nobody took that seriously enough to give the actor an accent training or redub the few words of dialogue.

Has anybody (from the production or among the actors) tried to explain this accent with a background story?

Comment: The comic book to movie world is rife with this. Look at Bane, didn't exactly sound like a Carribean accent to me. I feel that, in the case of the movies it is better to let these kinds of situation go rather than try and force an accent on the actor. Otherwise you end up with Anne Hathaway in `One Day`

Comment: But in the movie, Bane is not supposed to be from a Caribbean background (or I missed something)? This is not about inconsistencies between comic and movie but within the movie itself.

Comment: According to [his Wiki](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Georges_Batroc) Batroc is actually from Marseille and moved to Algeria later in life. - Maybe the movie version of this character grew up in Quebec?

Answer (score 3):

I know a lot of American's can't tell the difference between an Australian and a South African and a New Zealand accent. Maybe its the same issue, and no-one noticed that the somewhat frenchish accent wasn't actually French/Algerian.